# How Am i supposed to bind my variable to a img attribute in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

`<%=Eval(src) %>` is not working.

```
<img id="Img1" src="<%=Eval( src) %>" runat="server" alt="" />
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class image_from_cb : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string src="";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        src = "~/final.jpg";
    }
}
```

I know i can do this with Attribute.Add or with ASPIMAGE , but i was just wondering why <% %> is not working

Comment: <img id="Img1" src="<%= src %>" runat="server" alt="" />i tried this i dont why it didnt work

Comment: See my answer for another idea

Answer (score 1):

As You are using `runat="server"`, You can use

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    src = "~/final.jpg";
    Img1.src = src;        
}
```

Or if you want to use your `src` variable

```
 <img id="Img1" src='<%= src >%' alt="" />
```

Comment: `<%= src %>` won't work with a server control. You would need to remove the `runat`

Comment: i know Sir but i was wondering why this isnt working
 <img id="Img1" src="<%= src %>" runat="server" alt="" />

Comment: You cannot use code blocks on server controls. Either remove the `runat` or use set the property in the code behind as above.

Answer (score 0):

Try it
You can do this way

html

```
<img id="Img1"  runat="server" alt="" />
```

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Img1.src= "~/final.jpg";
    }
```

And Another way is

try this   **Page.DataBind();** in Page load event

Look at my sample code html

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <img id="Img1" src="<%# src.ToString() %>" runat="server" alt="" />

            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="myImage" ImageUrl="<%# src %>" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string src = "";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            src = "~/1455094_265560366930522_537876922_n.jpg";
            //Add this
            Page.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Easy coding !!The both ways working in my side